# Switching embedded youtube video playback with Images

Tags: image, wordpress, replace, youtube

I am looking to have an embedded youtube video with several images below it that correspond to different youtube videos. I want to set it up so that when an image is clicked on, the video above changes to whichever video corresponds with the clicked image. An implementation of this can be seen here: http://www.seanhayesmusic.com/2012/media/

I am trying to implement this into a wordpress site and I really only have skill in HTML and CSS. I would very greatly appreciate if someone could help me with the code for this!

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the source. it's just html. He's got the youtube video in an iframe, and there's an `<a>` tag around the thumbnails with target= attribute making the link change the iframe.

Alternatively, you could actually embed the video on the page, and use javascript (and jquery if you want it to be easier) to alter the embed code when you click on the thumbnails. This method would probably be better and easier.

1. Go to the youtube page for each video, click "share" then "embed" and copy the html.
2. While you're there, take a screenshot. Crop/resize to make the video thumbnail.
3. For the default video (the one that plays/shows before you click thumbnail) paste in the full embed code (from step 1) into your page. add this to the `<iframe>` tag: `id="video_player"`
4. For the other videos, put your thumbnail image on your page as normal, then add a `<a>` tag around the image like this: `<a href="#" onclick="$('#video_player').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/paPT5qxM9m0'); return false">` (except of course you need to fix the url, with the one in the embed code for that video
5. If you don't already have it, source jquery into your page. That means adding something like the following to your `<head>` tag: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Hey, I tried this here, http://www.earthamplified.com/look, but it just jumps to the top of the page and appends the # to the end of the url at the top rather then switching the video?

Comment: Oops, looks like I messed up on the quotes in the onclick handler. You may need to understand what's going on here to make it work. I just typed my ideas, I didn't test it.